# Importing project with built in graddle settings into intelliJ

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

The course I am doing currently uses a project with a gradle wrapper that I need to import to InteliJ. They say it should be done without downloading any additional things however I can make it work in IntelliJ. Below I am pasting the screenshot of the steps they are doing:

1. https://video.udacity-data.com/topher/2016/June/5771ef42_project-selection/project-selection.png
2. https://video.udacity-data.com/topher/2016/June/5772e151_external-model/external-model.png
3. https://video.udacity-data.com/topher/2016/June/5772e45d_gradle-wrapper/gradle-wrapper.png

The problem is that IntelliJ never shows me step 3. The course says that after step 2 I should click "next" button but there is no "next" button in my IDE only "finish" button. When I click the finish button I get "gradle sync error" which I think is caused by IntelliJ trying to download something while the PC is offline. What should I do to get to the third step and activate this "use gradle wrapper task configuration" option?

Comment: These screenshots are outdated. You just open the Gradle project using File | Open action and select the Gradle build file. What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: I was getting "Gradl syncing error" nothing more.But when I connected the PC to internet IntelliJ downlaoded something and opened the project.